# Test case fails due to missing parameter from call-back function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I have to write a test-case using karma to the following code.

```
$scope.getUserDetails = function (param) {
    Api.getData(param).then(function (result) {
        Api.getVal(result).then(function (data) {
            var display = Api.userDetails(result.id, result.name);
            $scope.username = display.name;     
        });
    });
};
```

But i am facing the problem because of test case fails due to missing parameter from call-back function. I tried many methods. But test-cases failed due to result.id is undefined. Following is just a scaffold of my test-case. 'apiCall' are defined in beforeEach.

```
it('should test the getData()', function () {
    var user = 'John';
    scope.getUserDetails(123);
    deferred.resolve(user);
    spyOn(apiCall, 'getData').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
});
```

Comment: where are you resolving the promise? Probably you have to mock this variable.

Comment: i guess you `user` should look more like: `user: {id: '123', name: 'John'}` your `user` from test is the `response` in code

Comment: @maurycy : Actually i defined `user` like that. But problem is call back values not getting in inner function.  The  test-case for the inner function is not written in above test-case.
Thanks...